# How complete is the WL's string language?

Tags: string-manipulation

Consider the following example:

Suppose I am interested in words that contain all the letter of the list `characters={"e","t","l","a","b"}` at least once. An example would be the word "abilities" or a more minimalist word would be "table".

If I try to use a general regular expression language then I can achieve this by:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin["(?=.*"<>#<>")"&/@characters,".*"]],IgnoreCase->True]
```

But I want to do this using `StringPatterns` only. Is there a way to do this?

Since I can't find the lookahead assertions in `StringPatterns` I try the following:

```
DictionaryLookup@PatternAnd[___~~"e"~~___,___~~"t"~~___,___~~"l"~~___,___~~"a"~~___,___~~"b"~~___]
```

But I can't find a `PatternAnd` that would work here. Does Wolfram language has such a pattern construct? I see there is `AnyOrder` which I try to use:

```
DictionaryLookup[___~~AnyOrder["e",___,"t",___,"l",___,"a",___,"b"]~~___]
```

It takes forever and doesn't end. Can someone help me to find a `StringPattern` that would achieve the result of the regex?

Comment: how could `"abilities"` come from list of chars when `i` is not even there? I deleted my answer until I understand better what is it you are asking.

Comment: @Nasser word must contain all the letters in the list at least once but may also contain any letter outside the list.

Comment: I see. when you say "any other letter." do you mean any ONE other letter, or can it contain more multiple number of other letters?

Comment: Once the condition of letters in the list is satisfied, there is no restriction at all. It can have any number of letters any number of times (just try to match the output of regex command).

Comment: Related to Daily Challenge (Day 9) [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1935390).

Answer (score 13):

The language has [`StringContainsQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringContainsQ.html) and [`ContainsAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAll.html), it seems we need a combination of the two:

```
StringContainsAll[string_String, patts_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   AllTrue[patts, StringContainsQ[string, #, opts] &];
StringContainsAll[patts_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]][x_] := 
    StringContainsAll[x, patts, opts]
```

Now you can get the word list with

```
Select[DictionaryLookup[], 
 StringContainsAll[{"e", "t", "l", "a", "b"}, IgnoreCase -> True]]
```

or, if you want a pattern test,

```
DictionaryLookup[
 StartOfString ~~ x__ ~~ EndOfString /; (StringContainsAll[x, {"e", "t", "l", "a", "b"}, 
    IgnoreCase -> True])]
```

edit: You can this function in the repository as [`ResourceFunction["StringContainsAll"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StringContainsAll)

Answer (score 7):

This only makes minimal use of string patterns (as with Jason B.'s answer, it builds on `StringContainsQ`), but it uses `Fold` in a way I don't think I've ever seen it used before, to get the elements of a list that satisfy a bunch of predicates. It is terribly efficient?

Maybe not. But I still think it's kind of cool:

```
Fold[Select, DictionaryLookup[], StringContainsQ /@ characters]
(* {aberrational, abhorrently, abilities, <<1071>>, worktable, worktables, writable} *)
```

Comment: +1 for innovative use of Fold!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a string patterns, how about set manipulation:

```
contains[word_, characters_] := Module[{chars, wordChars},
  wordChars = Union@Characters@word;
  chars = Union@characters;
  Intersection[chars, wordChars] == chars
  ]

contains["abilities", {"e", "t", "l", "a", "b"}]

(* True *)

contains["ability", {"e", "t", "l", "a", "b"}]

(* False *)
```

Although I do see your point -- you really want to do this with string syntax.